# Merge all txt files in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I have a series of txt files in a folder and I wanted to move these files to a data frame

but I only managed to do this by saving a csv file, how do I work with the data frame directly without having to save to a csv file?

follow my code below

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
main_folder = ('F:\PROJETOS\LOTE45\ARQUIVOS\RISK\RISK_CUSTOM_FUND_N1'

def get_filename(path):
filenames = []
files = [i.path for i in os.scandir(path) if i.is_file()]

for filename in files:
    filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    filenames.append(filename)
return filenames

files = get_filename(main_folder)

with open('some.csv', 'w',  encoding = 'utf8', newline = '') as csv_file:
for _file in files:

    file_name = _file
    with open(main_folder +'\\'+ _file,'r') as f:
        text = f.read()

        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([file_name, text])

df = pd.read_csv('some.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to run something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for _file in files:
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(_file),  ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a dictionary and turn it into a dataframe.

```py
# your code to obtain the files
data = {"filename":[], "text":[]}
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as file_object:
        content = file_object.read()
    data["filename"].append(file)
    data["text"].append(content)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
```